# z-index doesnt push the content on top of other content

Tags: css, z-index

I have the below code for Fuzzylogic and it works fine. Whenever I type any word in the search bar(header), the results are displayed but it overlaps the content. How can I get the display results appear over the content.

```
 '<div style="background-color:white;z-index:"200";"><a style="margin-left:2%;" href="' + result['itemCode'] + ' target="_blank" ">' + result['itemName'] + '</a></div>'
```

The content in the mainpage already has a z-index of 100 and so I gave 200

Comment: check this article: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1):

```
'<div style="background-color:white;z-index:"200";"><a style="margin-left:2%;" href="' + result['itemCode'] + ' target="_blank" ">' + result['itemName'] + '</a></div>'
```

The problem is you have put this quotation marks before and after the z-index value. 
Just remove those:

```
'<div style="background-color:white;z-index:200;"><a style="margin-left:2%;" href="' + result['itemCode'] + ' target="_blank" ">' + result['itemName'] + '</a></div>'
```

If the problem continues it means you need to specify position for at least one element. 
That means you need add position to this element.

Do like this:

```
'<div style="background-color:white;z-index:200;position:fixed"><a style="margin-left:2%;" href="' + result['itemCode'] + ' target="_blank" ">' + result['itemName'] + '</a></div>'
```

Comment: It wasnt working without quotes too. I just tried if it works, but it doesnt

Comment: Check the answer now